# using reduce vs map+reduce to sum digits of a number

Tags: javascript, reduce

If I'd have to sum digits of numbers I'd use(as a beginner) something like this:

```
num.toString().split('').map(Number).reduce((a,i) => { return a + i });
```

But I saw a solution which skips map and adds this in return statement `{return a + +i},0);`

So the complete solution is only:  `num.toString().split('').reduce((a,i) => {return a + +i},0);`

What does the plus in `+i` do and why do I have to explicitly initialize to 0 to make it work?

Comment: the `+` signs converts the object to number

`+'25'` gives you 25

Comment: `0` is the starting value of the accumulator

Comment: @Beingnin thanks, why do I get the original number if I don't explicitly specify the accumulator? I dont have to specify accumulator in the first case and it works.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, the first one works too. I get sum of all digits in number.

Comment: @Azm you didn't have to do it for the first case is coz the the input to reduce function is an array of number. so js engine defaults the default accumulator value as 0